# How to pass multiple forms serialized Object to an array Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple forms and I am doing the serialized array of my form.

Expectation:

1. I need to create an temporary object and I need to pass all the values of my form values into that object.

So in the below Code I have create a temp object `tmpObj`, i am trying to push all the iterated form values into the fields which are under tmpObj.

tmpObj has multiple attributes like field 1 and field 2, and it has attributes like firstname and lastname.

and i need to push this tmpObj to the `items` array.

My form has firstname and lastname, i need to iterate this forms and get the values of the firstname and lastname and i need to push it to the object and the object should be pushed to the items array.

But If am doing the serialize array, am able to push either firstname or lastname, only in firstname field.

Expected Output:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "fieldset": {
        "field1": {
          "firstName": "abc",
          "lastName": "def"
        }
      },
      "field2": {
        "firstName": "abc",
        "lastName": "def"
      }
    },
    {
      "fieldset": {
        "field1": {
          "firstName": "ghi",
          "lastName": "jkl"
        }
      },
      "field2": {
        "firstName": "ghi",
        "lastName": "jkl"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I tried:

HTML:

```
<form id="f1" class="forms">
      <div class="f-grp">
        <label for ="fn1">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fn1" id="fn1" />
      </div>
      <div class="f-grp">
        <label for ="ln1">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="ln1" id="ln1" />
      </div>
  </form>

  <form id="f2" class="forms">
      <div class="f-grp">
        <label for ="fn2">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fn2" id="fn2" />
      </div>
      <div class="f-grp">
        <label for ="ln2">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="ln2" id="ln2" />
      </div>
  </form>

  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#submit').click(function(){
        setFormObj();
      });
    });

    var setFormObj = function(){
      var self = this;
      self.myObj = {};
      myObj.items = [];
      self.tmpObj = {
        fieldset: {
          field1: {
            firstName: "",
            lastName: ""
          }
        },
        field2: {
          firstName: "",
          lastName: ""
        }
      };

      $('.forms').each(function(fKey, fValue){
        var _serArr = $(this).serializeArray();
        $(_serArr).each(function(sKey, sValue){
          var value = sValue.value;
          tmpObj.transferOldNumberInfo.addressfields.firstName = value;
        });

      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check jquery `.serializeArray()` function.

It takes an array and creates a set of key/value.

You can check doc [here](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).